# using apt to migrate from 1504 to 1604

Tags: apt

I forgot how to migrate from 1504 to 1604 using apt.  I am not sure how to do this it has been so long. I am not even sure where to look for this help.  Thank you

Comment: You'll need to go to 15.10 first, and 16.04 isn't out yet, plus it's LTS.  In any case, you can upgrade the OS with 'sudo do-release-upgrade'.

Comment: The final release of 16.04 will be available April 21st, it's still in Beta. Only a week or so, away.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade before the official release in April 21st you can open a terminal window and write

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

This will upgrade your system

If you wait the official release your ubuntu system will warn you about it and then you can upgrade.